# Is there an official historical term for the peephole (with a sliding shutter) in the castle and/or monastery entrance door?

Tags: terminology

I've searched and searched, and couldn't find anything sensible.

I mean, "Judas window" is associated more with prisons than convents.

And peepholes should not be rectangular, nor protected by sliding shutters on one side.

Is there a proper architectural term?

[image]

Comment: The most common terms I see are your [Judas Gate](https://www.finterio.be/en/product/judas-gate-large-1549) or the (obviously more modern term) [speakeasy window](https://www.wayfair.com/Perilla-Home--Cast-Iron-Safety-Speakeasy-Classic-Style-Grill-SE_88850199-L6490-K~DRIL1068.html?refid=GX263470411909-DRIL1068&device=c&ptid=1310652746868&network=g&targetid=pla-1310652746868&channel=GooglePLA&ireid=152338146&fdid=1817&gclid=Cj0KCQjwj5mpBhDJARIsAOVjBdqBvwxOtYKcAbZhgRbC0PVwayPItinY-gUZe3vXqE1-3dm4CBJl-sUaAvRQEALw_wcB).

Comment: Wikimedia Commons choose to sub-categorize [door viewers](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Door_viewers) into "peepholes", "peep windows" and "Non-optical, rectangular peepholes". Looking at the last two, I cannot really make out what discerns them, they both seem to fit what you are looking for.